# What is more memory efficient among BitSet, List and Set?

Tags: java, list, set, bitset

Does anyone draw a comparison among the BitSet, List, and Set for memory efficiency? I would like to know more about large datasets, especially, for inserting and searching the data.

Comment: differenet data structure are for different purposes. The 3 you mentioned mostly cannot replace each other and a comparision is not meaningful. There are plenty of online or paper resources to learn data structures.

Comment: @BingWang can you write specifically about the BitSet memory usage?

Comment: bitset memory footprint is very small, for example 2 bytes (plus overhead) hold 16 pieces of bit info. However, each piece is just on/off (or True/False) so it is not fair to say it is more memory efficient than a List. We can only say bitset is better than a list of boolean values in terms of memory usage.